# How to Hide a Button Until Receiving a Successful API Response? (In Bubble.io)

Tags: show-hide, bubble.io

I’m facing a challenge with my project’s API integration.

Here’s the use case: I need to fetch data from an API, and once I receive a successful response, I want to enable a copy button/icon to copy that content. However, during page load and while waiting for the API response, I need to hide the copy button. How can I achieve this functionality effectively?

Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried to manage with custom state but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the **Layout** tab for the button, disable "This element is visible on page load." That will hide it by default.
2. On the **Conditional** tab, create a condition and select "Get data from an external API" for the **Why**.
3. Choose your API provider from the pop up.
4. Complete the condition by pulling any field from the API and choosing "is not empty".
5. Click "Select a property to change when true" and choose "This element is visible". Make sure the box is ticked to show the element.

That's it!

[Here's a screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNGFn.png)